# How do I add new rows to SQL automatically by time?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

I'm a pretty new programmer and I'm working on a project that I'm not sure how to make work. I'm hoping for some advice please.

Part of the project I'm working on will be used by a company to allow employees to sign up for lunch from their computers. I'm doing the project in MVC ASP.NET

The interface will look something like this:

----------------------
|1200 | Employee Dropdown Name 1
|       Employee Dropdown Name 2
|---------------------
|1230 | Employee Dropdown Name 1
|       Employee Dropdown Name 2
|---------------------

and on and on and on.

With this company, everything has to be recorded and stored. So, I already have a table with employee information. That will populate the drop down areas. Lunch times need to be stored in the database so it can be searched years down the line. So it has to be in a table.

The table get more tricky because not every time of the day is available for lunch (i.e. - no lunches after 0430 and before 0800).

My question is about how to create the future time slots in the database.

I could obviously make the table with all of these rows already in places for several years down the line. That's time-consuming, though, and I'll have to go back in in several years and fix it. Horrible idea.

What I'd LOVE to do is make it so every 24 hours, the database just automatically adds new rows with the next days times available - so just increment (at midnight, the program will just add the next day's times associated with that date (so at midnight on February 6, 2020, it will create February 7, 2020 0000, February 7, 2020 0030, etc. I've studied a lot but I'm still beside myself on how to make this work.

Thanks in advance everyone!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you want to drive your interface from the database table so that the user can select Name 1 and Name 2 and a time slot and submit.

It sounds like you also want the available timeslots to be driven by the database also (ie, timeslot in table without names with it is availlable). This is not a good idea. As you mentioned, you would be inserting data that is not actually a record but a placeholder. That will be very confusing down the track when you come to query the data.

My approach would be to do the following:
* add NOT NULL constraints to all columns in your database (if your database supports this feature) or have your app complain very much about NULLS in any of the columns. There is no need for NULLS in your use case by the look of it.

- the database should have a CHECK constraint that the time is within the allowable time range, and (assuming employees can not double book time slots) a CHECK constraint that there is no overlapping time slots, and also a UNIQUE constraint that ensures no duplicate times.... adjust to suit your needs.
- your app populates times between 0800 and 1630 (8AM and 4:30PM) and also query the database for all records matching the current day so those booked slots can be removed from the list of available time slots... adjust to suit.
- your app sends the user request of name and time slot to the DB. All the critical requirements are accepted or rejected by the DB schema and if there is something wrong, display an appropriate error in the app.

This way, your database is literally storing records of booked lunches.
I would NOT go down the path of pre inserting as then it becomes more complex as some records are "real" and some are artificially generated records to drive a GUI...
If you can't do the time slot calculations in your app rather than in the DB, then at least use a separate table that is maintained by a worker thread in your app OR if your DB supports it, a Stored Procedure which returns a table of available time slots.
I would use the stored procedure if I was avoiding doing complex time calculations in my app (also avoids need to worry about time zones - if you make sure to only store and display UTC times in your DB).

Answer (score 0):

Having in mind structure like this:

*LunchTimeSlots* (id, time_slot)

*Employee* (id, name, preferred_time_slot_id, etc)

*Lunches*(employee_id, time_slot_id, date)

You need a scheduled job to add records to the "Lunches" table every midnight. How to define the job depends on your database vendor. But most of the popular rdbms have this feature. (f.e. [mssql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-job?view=sql-server-ver15))

---

Despite it's possible to do what you want with db schedulers or any other scheduler, i would recommend to avoid such db design. It's always better to write real facts to the database like a list of employees or fact that lunch was served 
to employee at 1pm today.

Unlike real facts, virtual data can be always generated "on-the-fly" by sql queries. F.e. by joining employees to list of dates from today till year 2100, we can get planned lunches for all employees for next 80 years.